how can i repeat a url multiple times in karate?
I am having a karate test . in my karate test i am issuing a post request . I want to run this post request multiple times (say for example 5) . how can i achieve this
@bing
Feature:test
  Background:
    * configure ssl = true
    * configure httpVersion = 'http2'
  Scenario: Test7 
    * def reqBody = read('Request.json')
    * def responseResult = read('Response.json')
    * def msurl= 'http://localhost:8090'

    * url msurl   // need to call this 4 times
    Given path '/ms/v3/clm'
    And request reqBody 
    When method post
    Then status 201
    And print response
    Then match response == responseResult 

    * url msurl   // just call this once.
    Given path '/ms/v4/clm'
    And request reqBody 
    When method post
    Then status 201

    * url msurl  // need to call this 4 times
    Given path '/ms/v3/clm'
    And request reqBody 
    When method post
    Then status 201
    And print response
    Then match response == responseResult 

thank you

Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57273444/is-there-a-way-in-karate-to-call-a-feature-multiple-time-using-karate-repeat-or
